# Find the percentage from a sum of percentages PHP

Tags: php, percentage

So I have a range of child items with their own percentages out of 100, and a parent item which is the sum of all these percentages out of 100:

```
 $parentItem['percent'] = sumOfAllChildren %
 $childItem1['percent'] = 50
 $childItem2['percent'] = 60
 $childItem3['percent'] = 100
 $childItem4['percent'] = 15
```

How could I calculate the sum for the parent item in this case using PHP?

Comment: This is more a mathematic question than a programming issue. http://math.stackexchange.com/ best suits your request.

Comment: I've got some questions. First of all: Are you sure you want to have the SUM of these percentages? You're sure you didn't mean the average percentage? If you mean the sum, simply calculate 50+60+100+15 what would give you 225 what doesn't make really sende I think. By the way, show us your code what you've tried so far :)

Comment: *sum of all these percentages out of 100* ? 225 would result more than 100%. I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I think u need average of them 225/4 = 56.25

Comment: Yes it is an odd one, so if you think of it in completion terms, to get 100 on the parent, you need 100 on all the children, so each child adds to the weight of the parent, ill edit the question to make more sense, but it is more of a math problem than a programming issue as @Zeratops states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope it is useful

```
 $childItem1['percent'] = 50;
 $childItem2['percent'] = 60 ;
 $childItem3['percent'] = 100 ;
 $childItem4['percent'] = 15  ;

$total=0;

$total+=$childItem1['percent']; 
$total+=$childItem2['percent']; 
$total+=$childItem3['percent'];
$total+=$childItem4['percent'];  

$percent=(100 / 400) * $total;

$parentItem['percent'] = $percent. "%";
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

calculate like this:

```
$children = [$childItem1, $childItem2, $childItem3, $childItem4];
$childPers = array_column($children, 'percent');
$parentItem['percent'] = array_sum($childPers)/(100 * count($childPers));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use array_sum function by refactoring your code slightly.

```
$children = [50,60,100,15];
$parent = array_sum($children); // would give you 225

// add a child
$children[] = 100;
$parent = array_sum($children); // would give you 325
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php for more info.